# Finding the set of generators of the ideal $I = (2, 1 + \sqrt{-5})$ of $R = \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

If I am given this ideal $I = (2, 1 + \sqrt{-5})$ clearly in the question, does that means that the set of generators of it is $\{ 2, 1 + \sqrt{-5} \}$? if so, is this the only set of generators of it in $R$? is this set linearly independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those are generators of the ideal. Given any set of generators of an ideal, you can always multiply the generators by units and keep the same ideal, so there are certainly other sets of generators (note that the only units in $R$ are $\pm 1$). A more interesting question and one that is often asked is whether the given ideal is principal, which is I believe what you are getting at in your linear independence question. To answer that more precisely however, you need to clarify what you mean by linearly independent? Over what set of scalars?

Comment: So in this ring those are the only set of generators? as the units are $\pm 1.$ ... am I correct?

Comment: I mean linearly independent over our $R.$

Comment: You see easily that if $\{2,1+\sqrt{-5}\,\}$ is a set of generators, so is $\{2,n+\sqrt{-5}\,\}$ for $n$ any odd integer.

Comment: You should also be able to see that your two generators *definitely are not* $R$-linearly independent.