# the set of generators of the ideal $I = (2, 1 + \sqrt{-5})$ of $R = \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

In this question here [Finding the set of generators of the ideal $I = (2, 1 + \sqrt{-5})$ of $R = \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4017116/finding-the-set-of-generators-of-the-ideal-i-2-1-sqrt-5-of-r-mat) @Noah has told me that yes $\{ 2, 1 + \sqrt{-5} \}$ are generators of my ideal $I$ of $R$ and @Lubin has written those 2 comments to me:

1 - We can see that, if $\{ 2, 1 + \sqrt{-5} \}$ is a set of generators, then so is $\{ 2, n + \sqrt{-5} \}$ for $n$ any odd integer .

2-our two generators $\{ 2, 1 + \sqrt{-5} \}$ definitely are not $R$-linearly independent.

But I am unable to prove these 2 comments, could someone show me the details of the proofs? why specifically an odd $n$ in $ 1 + \sqrt{-5} $ instead of the $1$ will make it also a generator, why the other generator $2$ should be left as it is? Is that related to the norm function of $R$?
Also,how to prove that our two generators $\{ 2, 1 + \sqrt{-5} \}$ definitely are not $R$-linearly independent?

Comment: 1. Odd numbers differ by a multiple of $2$. 2. They both divide $6$.

Comment: Oh @DietrichBurde do you mean when I write in bold, you understand that I am shouting ? I am so sorry, I did not mean that at all.

Comment: @DietrichBurde by the way I edited my post.

Comment: @Thorgott so can $\{ 1, 1 + \sqrt{-5} \}$ be a set of generators for our ideal $I$?

Comment: That's not even a subset of the ideal, so no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Generally, the ideal generated by two elements $a,b$ is the same as the ideal generated by $a$ and $a+b$, since it must also contain $b=(a+b)-a$.
   Applying it repeatedly (or proving right away in the above manner), we get
   $$(a,b)=(a,b+na)$$
   for every $n\in\Bbb Z$.
2. We have
   $$2\cdot(1+\sqrt{-5})-(1+\sqrt{-5})\cdot 2=0$$
   with both coefficients $2,\ (1+\sqrt{-5})$ being in $R$.

Comment: so can $\{ 1, 1 + \sqrt{-5} \}$ be a set of generators for our ideal $I$?

Comment: No, $1$ is not an element of the ideal.